# How can I make my FacetGrid plot work for the data below?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I've created a function for plotting the data (see below) using a FacetGrid.

```
def barplots(data, col, hue, x, y):

    sns.set_style(style="darkgrid")
    sns.set_context("paper", font_scale=2)
    g = sns.FacetGrid(
        data,
        col=col,
        hue=hue,
        palette="tab20c",
        legend_out=False,
        col_wrap=5,
        height=15,
    )
    g.map(sns.catplot, x=x, y=y)
    plt.show()


col = "military_civilian"
hue = "sex"
y = "age_at_selection"
x = "nationality_2"
data = nationality_astronauts

barplots(data, col, hue, x, y)
```

I keep getting ValueError: Could not interpret input 'nationality_2'

Can anybody figure out what's happening here?

| nationality_2 | military_civilian | sex | age_at_selection | age_at_selection | age_at_selection | hours_mission | eva_hrs_mission |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | youngest_selected | oldest_selected | average_age_selected | total_eva_hrs_mission | total_eva_hrs_mission |
| Canada | civilian | female | 29 | 38 | 32 | 805.75 | 0 |
| Canada | civilian | male | 30 | 50 | 37.57142857 | 11036.93 | 24.28 |
| Canada | military | male | 29 | 34 | 32.375 | 5410.02 | 22.01 |
| China | military | female | 34 | 34 | 34 | 303.5 | 0 |
| China | military | male | 32 | 45 | 40.15384615 | 3662 | 0.26 |
| France | civilian | female | 28 | 28 | 28 | 614.4 | 0 |
| France | civilian | male | 31 | 36 | 33.5 | 5127.63 | 13 |
| France | military | male | 27 | 42 | 34.28571429 | 9351.91 | 31.79 |
| Germany | civilian | male | 33 | 42 | 35.63636364 | 11584.06 | 12.97 |
| Germany | military | male | 34 | 39 | 36.4 | 8953.1 | 14.25 |
| Italy | civilian | male | 42 | 52 | 45.33333333 | 854.42 | 0 |
| Italy | military | female | 32 | 32 | 32 | 4783.5 | 0 |
| Italy | military | male | 33 | 41 | 36 | 17037.25 | 26.88 |
| Japan | civilian | female | 29 | 33 | 31.66666667 | 930.8 | 0 |
| Japan | civilian | male | 29 | 47 | 32.8125 | 32299.35 | 60.11 |
| Japan | military | male | 39 | 39 | 39 | 3400 | 0 |
| Rest of world | civilian | female | 26 | 28 | 27 | 450.22 | 0 |
| Rest of world | civilian | male | 25 | 46 | 34.9375 | 15783.61 | 105.8 |
| Rest of world | military | male | 27 | 42 | 34.64705882 | 17785.96 | 4.72 |
| U.S. | civilian | female | 26 | 47 | 32.34065934 | 77986.735 | 180.33 |
| U.S. | civilian | male | 25 | 60 | 35.41832669 | 142271.82 | 1266.607 |
| U.S. | military | female | 32 | 36 | 33.17647059 | 28430.5 | 105.42 |
| U.S. | military | male | 26 | 53 | 34.63807531 | 257079.295 | 1440.23 |
| U.S.S.R/Russia | civilian | female | 30 | 32 | 31.6 | 8767 | 3.58 |
| U.S.S.R/Russia | civilian | male | 25 | 48 | 33.325 | 227418.79 | 429.52 |
| U.S.S.R/Russia | military | female | 25 | 25 | 25 | 70.83 | 0 |
| U.S.S.R/Russia | military | male | 23 | 45 | 30.30481283 | 449779.468 | 933.707 |

Comment: Your source table has **3** columns named *age_at_selection*.
After reading, these columns are given names:  *age_at_selection*, *age_at_selection.1* and  *age_at_selection.2*.
Do you want all these 3 columns to be the source for consecutive rows?
And why did you pass *col_wrap=5*?
Place also some picture or describe some other way what data should be presented in each plot cell.

Comment: I've tried this but I'm still getting the same error. I just want to plot age_at_selection against nationality_2. I want to set hue='sex' and plot it on grid military_civilian. It seems as if it should be simple to do but the error remains. Not sure why

Comment: [Like this](https://imgur.com/a/VeGkOZ8)? And what do you mean by `plot it on grid military_civilian`? This category has exactly two values. Not much of a grid.

Comment: I'm trying to plot this on a FacetGrid with military_civilian being a column. Hope that's clear

Comment: @Mr.T that's what I was looking for, how did you manage that?

Comment: @Valdi_Bo thanks for spotting that! I've amended the source table now to what it should be.

Comment: Do you have a **multi-index** on columns? Your description is still unclear.

Comment: @Valdi_Bo that's correct, the columns are multi-indexed. Not sure how to flatten them out to a single index. What I'm trying to achieve is this > https://imgur.com/a/VeGkOZ8

Comment: `g.map(sns.barplot, data=data, x=x, y=y, hue=hue)`, and I removed `col_wrap` and `hue` from `FacetGrid`. However, it was not clear that you have a multi-index dataframe. You may want to read [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @Mr.T Thanks for the link. That solution doesn't work on the data I have. Maybe it's due to the multi-indexed columns

Comment: The link describes how you should provide sample data so that other SO users can reproduce your problem, not how to address your problem. Only if we can reproduce your problem, we can suggest how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions:

1. Change the index on columns to a single level:

   ```
   nationality_astronauts.columns = ['nationality_2', 'military_civilian', 'sex',
       'Youngest', 'Oldest', 'Average', 'hours_mission', 'eva_hrs_mission']
   ```
2. Generate the source data:

   ```
   data = nationality_astronauts.iloc[:, 0:6].melt(id_vars=['nationality_2', 
       'military_civilian', 'sex'], value_vars=['Youngest', 'Oldest', 'Average'],
       var_name='At selection', value_name='Age')
   ```

   The initial part of *data* is:

   ```
     nationality_2 military_civilian     sex At selection   Age
   0        Canada          civilian  female     Youngest  29.0
   1        Canada          civilian    male     Youngest  30.0
   2        Canada          military    male     Youngest  29.0
   3         China          military  female     Youngest  34.0
   4         China          military    male     Youngest  32.0
   ```
3. Create the plot, with separate rows for each *At selection*,
   corresponding to source *age* columns:

   ```
   g = sns.catplot(data=data, col='military_civilian', row='At selection',
       hue='sex', height=4, x='nationality_2', y='Age')
   g.set_xticklabels(rotation=90);
   ```

The result is:

[image]

If you want, pass any *palette* of your choice.

Comment: Thank you! I amended your solution a bit to fit my function by this is what I was looking for.